# Post Beam Connection

Tags: post, beam

I would like to connect beams to the lower part of posts that extend up to the top plate, to negate having to frame up walls.

I can't seem to find any information of code approval in the United States for a double-sided timber connector.

I realize that bolting beams to posts is not permitted but what about the combination of bolts and double-sided timber connectors? (*They are widely used in Europe*).

[image]

Comment: I don't for sure about those particular connectors, but there are definitely brackets that can be used in that matter, from observation. We do seem to have split-ring connectors that offer a similar function, but the site I found only mentions their use use in truss structures https://www.splitringconnectors.com

Comment: What area of the US are you in?  That can affect code.